# How to use getpass() with poll() to set time limit?

Tags: c, linux, input, stdin

I am using `poll()` along with `getpass()` to get input from user in limited time. It works, but instead of showing `message` given in `getpass()`, it doesn't shows `message` until pressing `enter key`. How can I use these two functions together so that `message` given in `getpass()` will be displayed without need to enter `enter key`, and time to enter password will be limited?

I tried to solve this by clearing `stdin` and `stdout`, but it did't work.

```
#include <poll.h>
struct pollfd mypoll = { STDIN_FILENO, POLLIN|POLLPRI };
if( poll(&mypoll, 1, 20000) )
{
    char *pass = getpass("\nPlease enter password:");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getpass function is obsolete.  Do not use it.

Here is the working example.  The program wait for 20 seconds. If user enters password in 20 seconds then program reads information to password otherwise inform user about time exceeded to enter password.The following example does not tunoff echo.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct pollfd mypoll = { STDIN_FILENO, POLLIN|POLLPRI };
    char password[100];

    printf("Please enter password\n");
    if( poll(&mypoll, 1, 20000) )
    {
        scanf("%99s", password); 
        printf("password - %s\n", password);
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Time Up");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The following example will turnoff echo. Works same as getpass. This works on linux/macosx, a windows version should use [Get/Set ConsoleMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    struct pollfd mypoll = { STDIN_FILENO, POLLIN|POLLPRI };
    char password[100];
    struct termios oflags, nflags;

    /* disabling echo */
    tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &oflags);
    nflags = oflags;
    nflags.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    nflags.c_lflag |= ECHONL;

    if (tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &nflags) != 0) {
        perror("tcsetattr");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Please enter password\n");
    if( poll(&mypoll, 1, 20000) )
    {
        scanf("%s", password);
        printf("password - %s\n", password);
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Time Up");
    }

    /* restore terminal */
    if (tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &oflags) != 0) {
        perror("tcsetattr");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are differences between getpass and scanf, the first turns echo off and first try to read from `/dev/tty` while the latter don't so scanf is **not** a drop in replacement. Next if you suggest to use `scanf`, you could at least not add an uncontrolled possibility for a buffer overflow and use `scanf("%99s", password);`

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks for pointing buffer overflow. Modified it in the answer. Yes scanf is not drop in replacement for getpass. If OP just want to get input from user in limited time then OP can use it. Provided another example which controls echo.